# Not able to build WSO2 orbit, kernel 4.2.0 and platform 4.1.7

Tags: maven, svn, wso2

I am trying to build wso2 from source. Am following their document from the site [1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Building+from+Source)

I downloaded orbit, kernel and platform from svn as follows

svn checkout https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/orbit/tags/4.2.0 wso2carbon-orbit.

svn checkout https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/tags/4.2.0 wso2carbon-kernel.

svn checkout https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.1.7 wso2carbon-platform.

I have done Maven and JDK installations.

1. When I run the Orbit (mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true) it builds but shows   loads of WARNINGS.

   1. When I run kernel, build fails with ERRORS :

---

```
WSO2 Carbon - Registry API ......................... FAILURE


[WARNING] Bundle org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.registry.api:bundle:4.2.0 : Instructions in Export-Package that are never used: javax\.servlet\.http
                javax\.servlet
                org\.apache\.lucene\..*|org\.apache\.lucene
Classpath: Jar:.

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default) @ org.wso2.carbon.registry.api ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.reporting.exec.DefaultMavenReportExecutor
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/aether/graph/DependencyFilter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2446)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1872)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:653)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:863)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:790)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:278)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:210)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:986)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:982)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:260)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:240)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.AbstractSiteRenderingMojo.getReports(AbstractSiteRenderingMojo.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.aether.graph.DependencyFilter
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:242)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    ... 60 more




[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default) on project org.wso2.carbon.registry.api: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site: org/sonatype/aether/graph/DependencyFilter

 Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>org.apache.axis2.wso2:axis2:1.6.1.wso2v10, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.sonatype.aether.graph.DependencyFilter
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :org.wso2.carbon.registry.api
```

---

Am not sure what am I missing and what change should I make to build this successfully. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Apache Maven 3.0.x and JDK 1.6 to build Carbon.

Comment: Yes.. There were known issues when building with Maven 3.2.x due to incompatibilities between Maven versions.

Comment: Thank you. Now I can build both orbit and kernel. But when I build Platform it throws new error

 Non-resolvable parent POM for org.wso2.carbon:integration:4.1.0: Failure to find org.wso2.carbon:carbon-parent:pom:4.1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.wso2.carbon:integration:4.1.0, /Users/manoj/.m2/repository/org/wso2/carbon/integration/4.1.0/integration-4.1.0.pom, line 21, column 9 -> [Help 2]

Comment: Not sure what exactly the issue is.. Somehow, the integration tests pom has a parent pom reference 4.1.0 but it should be 4.2.0. But I guess you can comment out the integration module if you are not planning to run product integration tests.